# What is the difference between $ and [] in terms of the output in R ? when I extract data.frame

Tags: r

I use package 'tidytuesdayR'

```
target<-tidytuesdayR::tt_load(2021,30)
df<-target$drought

df$map_date
df[,1]
```

What is the difference between `df$map_date` and `df[,1]` in terms of the output? What functions will you use to explain the differences between them?

Comment: I don't have the package installed, but assuming that `map_date` is the first variabble in the data frame, there is no difference between the two in terms of their output. They both extract a variable from a data frame and return a vector.

Comment: Adding to @Phil. Your `df` is a `tibble`, which is a kind of a `data.frame`. However, there are some differences between a `tibble` and a `data.frame`. When using `$` to extract a column you will get a vector in either case. However, extracting a column from a `tibble` via e.g. `df[,1]` the result will still be a `tibble`, while in case of a `data.frame` the result will by default be simplified to a vector. As a consequence, using `$` or `[]` will return different objects in case of a tibble and hence the output printed in the console will be different as well.

Comment: This link may be useful: https://adv-r.hadley.nz/subsetting.html

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1169456/680068

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45918827/difference-between-and-operators-for-subsetting - A detailed look at differences, but the question is more about the unpredictable nature of data.frame subsetting than the operators more generally.

Answer (score 0):

### `x$var` is a shorthand for `x[["var"]]`

#### There are two main differences:

##### 1. `$` cannot be used with a character variable

Eg:

```r
### All examples are from Hadley Wichams _Advanced R_ - see link at end of answer.
var <- "cyl"
# Doesn't work - mtcars$var translated to mtcars[["var"]]
mtcars$var
#> NULL

# Instead use [[
mtcars[[var]]
#>  [1] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 6 8 8 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 4 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 8 6 8 4
```

#### 2. `$` uses left-to-right partial matching

This makes it convenient for interactive use, but unpredictable. For this reason, many people use `[[` rather than `$` when writing function and scripts, and use `$` for convenience whilst interacting directly with data.

Partial matching example:

```r
x <- list(abc = 1)
x$a
#> [1] 1
x[["a"]]
#> NULL
```

##### Further reading

For more info on these operators, and a reasonably thorough look "under the hood" of the R engine, check out Hadley's [Advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/), which is available for free online. These examples are reproduced from his [section on subsetting](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/subsetting.html#section-1).

Answer (score 0):

$ is 1-dimension vector not including name of column
[] is data.frame so including name of column

Comment: This isn't quite true: Data frames return a vector when you subset a single column, regardless of whether you subset using `$` or `[`. It's only possible to subset one column with `$`, so `$` _always_ returns a vector, whereas `[` sometimes returns a vector and sometimes returns a data.frame.